# Creating new lines based on another line feature and point feature using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector

I have line layer (roads) and point layer (milestones) and I need to create a new line layer based on roads layer, where the start and the end points will be milestone points.

[image]

Can you advise me some tool or script to create it?

when I try use in **Qgis Split lines at points** I get this:

[image]

Comment: Dissolve -> [Split Line at Point](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/split-line-at-point.htm). You need to choose QGIS och ArcGIS or your question will probably be put on hold.

Comment: In this case I exclude arcgis, beacause I don't have licence for this tool..

Comment: To tag a question with PyQGIS you should include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I think there's a bug in the `split line at points` tool. I used it recently (in QGIS 3.4) and got a similar result, with lines that extended far off the screen.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's a bug in the `split line at points` tool. I used it recently (in QGIS 3.4) and got a similar result, with lines that extended far off the screen. I haven't gotten around to [making a bug report](https://issues.qgis.org) yet. If you make one, please provide a link in a comment (or edit it into your question, if you don't have the commenting privilege yet).

Here's a workaround using the similar tool, `split lines with lines`.

1. Convert your points into short line segments with the `geometry by expression` tool. Use an expression like this:

   ```
    make_line($geometry, translate( $geometry,1,1))
   ```
2. Use the SAGA tool `split lines with lines` -or- the QGIS tool `split with lines`. Both worked for me, but the QGIS tool was significantly faster.

Comment: Thank you very much..I'll try it