# Merging Degree Two nodes in Stream Network using QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, postgresql, merge, stream

I have a stream network and I want to convert it in graph like data structure, for which I need to have precise set of FROM and TO vertices.The geometry of stream network is not correct i.e. the stream segments are not split at intersection on stream network.So, I have to merge the degree two nodes in the network so that my network will have only 1 and 3 degree vertices. The label in the figure represents the stream vertex id and degree of the vertex (ID-Degree) . The degree is the total amount of incoming or outgoing edge in the network.I have two shape-files, one is point layer having vertex ID and degree of each vertex and other is stream network having TO and FROM attributes for each edge but with degree 2 vertex as well which is to be eliminated.

[image: Stream Network]

I want it to convert as below.

[image: Final Stream Segment]

My approach:- For each edge , I will check the degree of the respective vertex ( assuming any starting vertex) and if the degree is not either 1 or 3 (degree greater than 3 is not expected) then the respective edge is merged and the iteration continues else the next vertex pair is considered.

I think there must be a easier way available as a plugin or Postgres/Postgis based query,please point out to any such tool or modified approach to achieve the same.

Comment: You could `dissolve` the lines, then select the points that end in `-1` or `-3` and use `split lines at points` to split the dissolved lines at those points.

Comment: @csk the "split lines at points" is not giving the desired output despite putting various tolerance values. Can you please provide an alternative for it?

Comment: Are you having the issue described here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315042/creating-new-lines-based-on-another-line-feature-and-point-feature-using-qgis ?

Comment: What do u call **'merging nodes'** since there is no geometry change ? Is this question your june 1st question "rephrased" ? I mean ... did u find the intersection points ?

Comment: Merging is regarding edges connected by nodes having degree 2 (in either vertex) which can be seen in second image given in question.

Comment: But u're not modifying any geometry ... can u answer my previous questions ?

Comment: By geometry modification I mean the edges are to be union-ed by st_union.No, the question is not rephrased. Yes the intersection points are found using any of qchainage,line intersections , build graph,etc

Comment: If u're able to find the 'intersections' (degree 3 or more nodes) u're able to find the intersections between them (sharing a common line intersection) and then find the isolated edges (the endpoints of which giving u the 1 degree nodes), am i wrong ? what do u want more ?

Comment: I want the stream network to be connected via only 1 and 3-degree nodes but the current network has degree 2 nodes as well and so the stream segments are broken there which needs to be merged with the neighbouring edges having only 1 or 3-degree nodes.